# Is energy conserved in a geodesic?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, geodesics, gravitational-redshift

In old school physics we know that

Work done (resulf of energy) $=$ Force $×$ displacement.

But, according to Einstein, free-fall is not a result of a force but just the result of objects following the geodesic.

which means,

W $= 0 \ ×$ displacement $\ = \ 0\ $ joule.

So, how can photons change its colors in a gravitational field? If gravitational field doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the metric of spacetime does not have an explicit dependence on certain coordinates, a corresponding quantity will be conserved along geodesics. Specifically for your question, if the metric does not depend on time, meaning that it is static and unchanging with time, energy will be conserved along the geodesic.

Now, the complication comes when you talk about *measuring* this energy, because the energy that you measure will depend on your position and your velocity in spacetime. If you're an observer in Schwarzchild spacetime (for a black hole), you can show that the energy of a photon will be measured to be less when it is far away from the hole compared to when it is closer. This is gravitational redshift.

An interpretation of this redshift is in terms of gravitational potential energy. As the photon gets out of the gravitational field, it gains gravitational potential energy. Since energy is conserved, its own "kinetic energy" must drop, thus it gets redshifted.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem. If I've answered your question sufficiently, please consider accepting it, thank you.